# @react-native-firebase/messaging getInitialNotification returned null

Tags: react-native-firebase

package.json

"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.3.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.3.0",

App.js

```
firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification().then(message => {
  console.log(
    'Notification caused app to open from quite state:',
    message,
  );
  if (message != null && message.data) {
    Common.handlePushNavigation(this.props.navigation, { type: message.data.type, target: message.data.target });
  }
});
```

And message was null in iOS.
Android works well.

I tried to change firebase versions but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was using
"@notifee/react-native": "^7.0.4"
for foreground messaging process.

And this hooked the outside notification of iOS app into it's own process.
So I downgraded that library version into 5.* and it worked well.